# Javascript countdown then count-up from a prompted variable?

Tags: javascript

Please Help! I'm new to Javascript, so there's probably an easier solution to this. Basically, I need it to prompt for a number and then count down from that number to zero. Once it reaches zero, I need it to count-up and stop at the same prompted number.

I got it to count down at first, then I completely butchered it, I have no clue what to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // get number from user
var startNum = parseInt(prompt("Input a number to start counting down from.",""));

var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

console.log(startNum);

function timer() {
    startNum--; // reduce number by 1
    console.log(startNum); 
    if (startNum <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
}

var counter = setInterval(timer2, 1000);

var endNum = 0

function timer2() {
    console.log(endNum)
    endNum++; // add number by 1
    console.log(endNum); 
    if (endNum >= startNum) {
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: When you cancel the first setInterval, you then want to start the second one. The way you have it now, they are both running at the same time. Also, you are modifying startNum so by the time you start the second timer, you don't know where to count up to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple issues here. the first one was pointed out by Rob in the comments. You're running both functions at the same time.

The other issue you have is that you're never storing the number. You're just subtracting and adding to nothing essentially.

So -

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // get number from user
var startNum = parseInt(prompt("Input a number to start counting down from.",""));
var currentNum = startNum;

var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
    console.log(currentNum);
    currentNum -= 1; // reduce number by 1
    console.log(currentNum);
    if (currentNum == 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        counter = setInterval(timer2, 1000);
    }
}

function timer2() {
    console.log(currentNum)
    currentNum += 1; // add number by 1
    console.log(currentNum); 
    if (currentNum == startNum) {
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
}
    </script>
```

Something like this should do the trick. Basically creating another variable to hold your start number and consider that the current number and the value that is going to change.

here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/w5FM6/

cheers

Comment: Woohoo! Thank you! Took off the extra console.logs and it worked perfectly!